# Conditional Left Join MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I have here a query that updates some fields based on a lookup table via left join.

```
UPDATE finalTbl
LEFT JOIN LookupTbl ON (finalTbl.Product = LookupTbl.Product) AND (finalTbl.Detail1 = LookupTbl.[Product Detail])
SET finalTbl.Description = LookupTbl.Description, finalTbl.Category = LookupTbl.Category;
```

Now, There's another field in `finalTbl` that i would like to include in the process (`Detail2`).

The idea will be..

if `finalTbl.Detail2 IS NULL` then `LEFT JOIN LookupTbl ON (finalTbl.Product = LookupTbl.Product) AND (finalTbl.Detail1 = LookupTbl.[Product Detail])`

else

`LEFT JOIN LookupTbl ON (finalTbl.Detail2 = LookupTbl.[Product Detail])`

- `Detail2`doesn't need to rely on `Product` field, compared to `Detail1`

I tried to create it via Design View but failed. Seems I am lost and need some light about it. Thanks for your inputs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but I often use `NZ` in joins where a date may be missing.
For example:  `Table0.ShiftDate<=NZ(Table1.EndDate,#01/01/9999#)`

Try:

```
UPDATE finalTbl LEFT JOIN LookupTbl ON (finalTbl.Product = LookupTbl.Product) AND 
                                       (NZ(finalTbl.Detail1,finalTbl.Detail2) = LookupTbl.[Product Detail])
SET   finalTbl.Description = LookupTbl.Description
    , finalTbl.Category = LookupTbl.Category;
```

**Edit:**
After a quick test it appears to work using the SQL below.

```
 SELECT *
 FROM  finalTbl LEFT JOIN LookupTbl ON (finalTbl.Product = LookupTbl.Product) AND 
                                       (NZ(finalTbl.Detail1,finalTbl.Detail2) = LookupTbl.[Product Detail])
```

**Edit again:**
But I haven't taken this into account.

> Detail2doesn't need to rely on Product field, compared to Detail1

Comment: This is the thing that I was looking for. I just started with `Detail2` as the required field. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad that worked.  Was playing around with removing the join to the product field and tried `FROM  finalTbl LEFT JOIN LookupTbl ON IIF(ISNULL(finalTbl.Detail1),TRUE=TRUE,finalTbl.Product = LookupTbl.Product)` which didn't throw an error, but didn't quite work either.